# how do I position my green button next too my red button instead of under my red button

Tags: html, css

I need to change where my green button is on the screen. when I created the button it automatically went under my other red button and I want the buttons to be next to each other. I haven't tried anything as I am an inexperienced programmer and I couldn't think of anything to try. I apologize for the poor wording as my English is not very good. help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

.netflix {
    color: white;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    position:relative;
    background: red;
    /*background-image: url(netflix\ black\ logo.png);
    background-size: cover;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
}


.netflix:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.hulu {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    background-image: url(hulu.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    background: lightgreen;
}

.hulu:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

/*div {
    width: 310px;
    height: 169px; 
    background-image: url(netflix\ black\ logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4;
    /*margin-right: 2px;*/
    /*margin-left: 5px;*/
    /*align-self: center;
}*/

/*p {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 176px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}*/
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>entertainment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shop.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  action="https://netflix.com/" target="_blank">
        <button class="netflix">
            <!--div>
            </div>
            <p>visit netflix and stuff </p-->
        </button>
    </form>
    <form>
        <button class="hulu">
        </button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp) layout to align your elements:

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;  /* <- It will make children align in the same row */
}

.netflix {
    color: white;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    position:relative;
    background: red;
    /*background-image: url(netflix\ black\ logo.png);
    background-size: cover;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
}


.netflix:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.hulu {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    background-image: url(hulu.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    background: lightgreen;
}

.hulu:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>entertainment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shop.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  action="https://netflix.com/" target="_blank">
        <button class="netflix">
            <!--div>
            </div>
            <p>visit netflix and stuff </p-->
        </button>
    </form>
    <form>
        <button class="hulu">
        </button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` **flex container** expands items to fill available free space or shrinks them to prevent overflow.

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

.inline {
display: flex;
}

.netflix {
    color: white;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    position:relative;
    background: red;
    /*background-image: url(netflix\ black\ logo.png);
    background-size: cover;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
}


.netflix:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.hulu {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    background-image: url(hulu.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    background: lightgreen;
}

.hulu:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

/*div {
    width: 310px;
    height: 169px; 
    background-image: url(netflix\ black\ logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4;
    /*margin-right: 2px;*/
    /*margin-left: 5px;*/
    /*align-self: center;
}*/

/*p {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 176px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}*/
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>entertainment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shop.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="inline">
            <form  action="https://netflix.com/" target="_blank">
        <button class="netflix">
            <!--div>
            </div>
            <p>visit netflix and stuff </p-->
        </button>
    </form>
    <form>
        <button class="hulu">
        </button>
    </form>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the 2 forms in a `<div class="button-list">`

```
.button-list {
  display: flex;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/qavepej/1/edit?html)

Note: There might be a better way than to wrap every button in a form tag. You could use hidden  or use javascript form submit to give you more flexibility and cleaner html.